# "Referrer" versus "referral" versus "referer"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

Which word is correct and what do they mean?

I've seen `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (PHP), but I have also seen *referrer* in [can I forward “referrer” information to other address?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/can-i-forward-referrer-information-to-other-address)
and *referral* on [the Wikipedia article about referral marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referral_marketing).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's start with an example from the "real world". When a doctor refers the patient to a specialist, the doctor is giving this person a *referral* to a specialist.  When the patient then sees the specialist, that specialist could think of the original doctor as the patient's *referrer*.

So, in my opinion the more suitable HTTP term for the URL that brought the user to the current web page is **referrer**. It is like if that previous URL gave the user the referral to the current page and is therefore the user's referrer to it.

And *referer* is just a misspelling of *referrer*.

Comment: AAAh. So it's just their "custom" English word, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, referrer and referal are both common English words that are used outside the Internet/HTTP context. As for HTTP_REFERER, I believe *referer* came as a misspelling of  *referrer*.

Comment: Yes, `HTTP_REFERER` is an unfortunate case of a misspelling being set in stone by putting it in a stanard (namely [RFC 1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt)).

Comment: @roth, With respect to your doctor example what will the specialist be called? Is the specialist also called the referral?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
"Referrer" and "Referral" refers to different things.

"Referrer" is something or somebody who refers.

"Referral" is the *act* of referring.

> A referral occurs when a referrer refers something. <s>Semantic Satiation</s>

["referer" :](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/referer?o=100074)

> Computing Dictionary
>   referer definition
>   World-Wide Web
>    A misspelling of "referrer" which somehow made it into the HTTP standard. A given web page's referer (sic) is the URL of whatever web page contains the link that the user followed to the current page. Most browsers pass this information as part of a request.
>   (1998-10-19)

Comment: I don't want to know what "Referral marketing" is. But thanks, i'll read it all

Comment: Those examples I given are only to demonstrate where I have seen it. I just want to answer what "Referrer", "Referral", "Referer" mean