# Why is the correct spelling of "referrer" with double "r"?

Tags: orthography

Why is the correct spelling of "referrer" with double "r"? Comparison with for example "referee" or "laborer" would lead one to conclude "referer" is the correct spelling. Is there some rule that applies to this situation or is it an exception?

Comment: Related: [“Referrer” versus “referral” versus “referer”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33135/referrer-versus-referral-versus-referer)

Comment: The stress is different in "referee" and "referrer"